# Finding shortest snippet in a document

Tags: java

for this problem I am trying to find out the minimum length of a string that a certain sequence can be found, e.g. in the string "122321" finding 1 and 3 my code should return index 3 as starting position and index 5 as the ending. The problem I'm having is when there are duplicates, then my position array is overwritten for that position.

What I have so far, given a document to search and a list of terms

```
for (String s : terms) {
     for (String find : document) {
          if (find.equals(s)) {
              positions[termsIndex] = documentIndex;
           }
           termsIndex++;
      }
      documentIndeX++;
 }
```

The problem with my algorithm right now is that it rewrites the positions when it encounters something twice. I'm looking for pointers on how to check the snippet I have to make sure it is the minimum, thanks.

Comment: The description of the problem and what you're trying to achieve is not clear. I don't understand what you're trying to do with the indices and why are you choosing 1,3,5 etc.

Comment: ... and if we don't understand what you are trying to do, we can't help.  Apart from giving generic advice like "try using a debugger".

Comment: Also, if this is a homework/coursework question, please say so.